# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a stored procedure but it shows me this kind of error. Please Check my code and guide me.

```
$add=0;
$sql =array();
foreach ($insert_array as $sizekey => $size) {
    foreach ($size as $colorkey => $color) {
        foreach ($color as $claritykey => $clarity) {
            foreach ($clarity as $cpskey => $cps) {
                foreach ($cps as $fluorkey => $array) {
                    $sub_array = explode("&", $array);
                    $rap        = $sub_array[0];
                    $difference = $sub_array[1];
                    $sec_disc   = $sub_array[2];
                    $old_dollar = $sub_array[3];
                    $new_disc   = $sub_array[4];
                    $new_dollar = $sub_array[5];

                    if(mysql_query("CALL `insert_tblcompareRec`('".$sizekey."','".$colorkey."','".$claritykey."','".$cpskey."','".$fluorkey."','".$rap."','".$difference."','".$sec_disc."','".$old_dollar."','".$new_disc."','".$new_dollar."') "))
                    {
                        $add++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo mysql_error();
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Dont use the nested **for** loops. Use seperate functionality for these to implement. This will affect your performance very badly.

Comment: don't use nested foreach loop

Comment: @BitsPlease Still Not Working.i am using only foreach loop.and same error occure.